# Allow user to customize HTML in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to design a CMS-like system that allows a user to modify HTML within their site. The problem is that we're using Razor as the view engine and I am trying to think of a strong strategy that will allow the user to edit all their HTML and still keep the razor functionality like loops where you would have a list articles or something along those lines.

I'm also not sure how the file system would work. Can/should you store a modified razor html page in a database? Or would you have to overwrite the literal file on the disk.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't give em the ability to directly edit your Razor files. That would be way too unsafe and you might not sleep well if you give users that you (apparently) do not trust such power. Give em [`DotLiquid`](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/).

So here are some interesting reads:

- For you: https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid/wiki/DotLiquid-for-Developers
- And for your users: https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid/wiki/DotLiquid-for-Designers

Comment: DotLiquid is absolutely awesome. Thank you.